# More concise way of writing this array inclusion / default fallback code?

Tags: ruby, default-value, ternary-operator, sanitization

I find that I've been doing this a fair enough number of times in my Rails controllers that I'm interested in finding a better way of writing it out (if possible).  Essentially, I'm validating the input to a few options, and falling back on a default value if the input doesn't match any of the options.

```
valid_options = %w(most_active most_recent most_popular)
@my_param = valid_options.include?(params[:my_param]) ? params[:my_param] : 'most_recent'
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you're doing it now. Any terser than that and you'll just end up sacrificing readability for a few less characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a hash instead of an array, it would be faster and cleaner. And, since your default is `"most_recent"`, having `"most_recent"` in `valid_options` is redundant. You better remove it.

```
filter_options =
Hash.new("most_recent")
.merge("most_popular" => "most_popular", "most_active" => "most_active")

@my_param = filter_options[params[:my_param]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something along the lines of a hash would be faster and that I could possible use the `#fetch` method for a fallback value, but the idea of supplying a fallback value to the `#new` operator is actually a good idea, I like it!  Going to leave the question open for a bit to see if there are any other ideas, but if nothing better, then I'll probably accept this one.

Comment: Feel free to accept any answer. Using `fetch` will also work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I too would go the Hash route.

This could be imaginable:

```
Hash[valid_options.zip valid_options].fetch(params[:my_param], "most_recent")
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the below:

```
valid_options = %w(most_active most_recent most_popular)
valid_options.detect(proc{'default_value'}){|i| i == params[:my_param] }
```

Another one:

```
valid_options = %w(most_active most_recent most_popular)
valid_options.dup.delete(params[:my_param]) { "default" }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit farfetched.

```
valid_options = %w(most_active most_recent most_popular)
(valid_options & [params[:my_param]]).first || 'most_recent'
```